# Why can some characters in this SVG not be found or browsed (searching with Ctrl+F) in Firefox and Safari on macOS but works on other browsers?

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, safari, svg

I reproduced this bug on two different computers (both running macOS High Sierra). On one of them, I performed a clean install Mozilla Firefox for the first time, just to test this bug. The version of Firefox Used was 61.0.1. The version of Safari used is 11.1.1,

Please behold [the following SVG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/Group_structure_and_statistics_of_%E2%80%9CGourmet_Master_Co._Ltd.%E2%80%9D%2C_as_of_31_December_2017_-_%E3%80%8C%E9%96%8B%E6%9B%BC%E7%BE%8E%E9%A3%9F%E9%81%94%E4%BA%BA%E8%82%A1%E4%BB%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8%E3%80%8D%E7%9A%84%E9%9B%86%E5%9C%98%E6%9E%B6%E6%A7%8B%E5%8F%8A%E7%B5%B1%E8%A8%88%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%AA%E8%87%B32017%E5%B9%B412%E6%9C%8831%E6%97%A5.svg) published [at Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Group_structure_and_statistics_of_%E2%80%9CGourmet_Master_Co._Ltd.%E2%80%9D,_as_of_31_December_2017_-_%E3%80%8C%E9%96%8B%E6%9B%BC%E7%BE%8E%E9%A3%9F%E9%81%94%E4%BA%BA%E8%82%A1%E4%BB%BD%E6%9C%89%E9%99%90%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8%E3%80%8D%E7%9A%84%E9%9B%86%E5%9C%98%E6%9E%B6%E6%A7%8B%E5%8F%8A%E7%B5%B1%E8%A8%88%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%AA%E8%87%B32017%E5%B9%B412%E6%9C%8831%E6%97%A5.svg).

A lot of strangeness is going on with this.

Please allow me to, below, report the bug as experienced on one of the computers (on the other device, the behavior on Safari is identical, the behavior on Firefox not identical in that sometimes more instances can be found and browsed through but similar in that still not all instances can be found and browsed through, at least for some of the strings).

---

When I browse for the string:

- *and*

I get

- `1 match` on Safari; i.e. I can only reach **1 of the 5 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 5 instances, but I can only toggle from `1 of 5 matches` through `1 of 3 matches` before getting the statement `Reached end of page, continued from top`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can only reach **3 of the 5 matches**.

---

When I browse for the string:

- *公司*

I get

- `47 matches` on Safari; i.e. I can reach all, i.e. **47 of the 47 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 47 instances, but I can only focus on one instance, namely `35 of 47 matches` before getting the statement `Reached end of page, continued from top`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can only focus on  **1 of the 47 matches**.

---

When I browse for the string:

- *這一鍋*

I get

- `1 match` on Safari; i.e. I can reach all, i.e. **1 of the 1 matches**; and
- on Firefox, if I press `Highlight All` it correctly highlights the 1 instance, but I can not focus on it, I only get the statement `Phrase not found`. In other words, using the up and down arrows that would normally focus through the results, I can focus on  **0 of the 1 matches, which is not even recognized as a match**.

---

Peers on other operating systems have informed me that they were unable to reproduce this bug with the mentioned file (one on Windows tried using Firefox and another peer on Gentoo Linux also tested on Firefox).

**NOTE:** A similar bug report for Firefox has been [posted here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1202150?&mobile=0).

**NOTE:** I have also filed this at [a bug at Bugzilla here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1475180).

Comment: If someone can reproduce this bug, please let us know.